# API / Server Issue Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

At 9am this morning I found that my server was unresponsive I was unable to connection into via either ssh or http/s.
When I finally logged in, everything was fine other then a high cpu (averaging 70-80%). Via the console I see that the disk IO was high and also there was a peak in the amount of API requests per second.

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can find out what happened ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you experienced was most likely the result of the networking issue described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-operations/6bKMTi2_DBc). Also, in general, this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gce-operations) is a good source to stay updated.

Beyond this, if the time window does not line up with your observations (there's no time zone specified in the question), one would need logs (i.e. Apache's, syslog, etc) in order to determine a possible cause, albeit it can turn into an exercise in speculation after the fact.